# Unable to Post Data to Salesforce in UAT Servers

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I have created a api request to post form data to create a lead in salesforce.

First I requested authorization key to insert data to salesforce
(Using oauth,client id and client secret.)

This works locally and data successfully posted in salesforce.
Next I moved this code to UAT server. In that UAT server I'm not able to get the authorization key and data is not posting to salesforce

Below I attched the error in LOG file

```
 //Function to Get Authorization
        public static string GetAuthorizationKey(ApiAuthorizeModel apiAuthorizeModel)
        {
            try
            {
                string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
                string AuthToken = string.Empty;
                string Error = string.Empty;
                string ErrorDescription = string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiAuthorizeModel.ClientID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiAuthorizeModel.ClientSecret) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiAuthorizeModel.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiAuthorizeModel.Password) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiAuthorizeModel.TokenURI))
                {
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var request = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>{
                {ApiConstants.Grant_type, ApiConstants.Password},
                {ApiConstants.Client_key,apiAuthorizeModel.ClientID},
                {ApiConstants.Client_secret, apiAuthorizeModel.ClientSecret},
                {ApiConstants.Username, apiAuthorizeModel.UserName},
                {ApiConstants.Password, apiAuthorizeModel.Password}
                });

                        request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
                        var response = client.PostAsync(apiAuthorizeModel.TokenURI, request).Result;
                        jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
                    Error = (string)jObject[ApiConstants.error];
                    ErrorDescription = (string)jObject[ApiConstants.error_description];
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error))
                    {
                        AuthToken = (string)jObject[ApiConstants.AccessToken];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.Error(Error, typeof(SendDataToApi));
                        Log.Error(ErrorDescription, typeof(SendDataToApi));
                        isAPIErrorFlag = true;
                    }
                }
                return AuthToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("Method : GetAuthorizationKey :", e, typeof(SendDataToApi));
                Log.Error(string.Concat("GetAuthorizationKey: ", e.Message.ToString()), typeof(SendDataToApi));
                return null;
            }
        }
```

> 2656 18:37:22 INFO  Method : GetAuthorizationKey
>   :System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond 101.53.162.131:443    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)

Comment: The IP address may be blocked.  So first try to PING using cmd.exe >Ping 101.53.162.131.  If ping works than the port number is being blocked or you cannot authenticate.  Port 443 is SSL/TTL which requires a certificate and the user cannot get the certificate.

Comment: Where I need to go to unblock this. Can you Please help on this ? . Please share me the steps to unblock/Certificate generation Process ?

Comment: First verify it is a port block, or a bad certificate (or wrong location), or bad IP.  A sniffer like wireshark or fiddler can help.  You should be using a secure connection https which first uses TCP to get SSL/TLS secure connection before making the http request.

Comment: where is your UAT server hosted? do you manage it? If you are managing it then it will be easy to unblock communication or if there is network team involved they will be able to modify in firewall rules. This is surely a connectivity problem.

Comment: I can't add the firewall the in the UAT client. this is our client server. I need to help client network team to do this. but i have no idea about how to do that. Can you please share the steps to do this.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1 Do I need to  white list all these IP's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your valuable comments. I have used this information to establish connectivity between your CRM servers and proxy server.

Depending on your environment, configure the server to allow traffic through the proxy at the machine.config or server’s root web.config (IIS level).

```
<system.net> 
    <defaultProxy> 
            <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress="http://ip address:port" bypassonlocal="false"/> 
    </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

It solves my problem.
The below site that i refered

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mdc_crm_server_proxy_configuration.htm&type=5